# Qt shared_ptr signal with QThreadPool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to process large csv data as it comes in chunk. If I run chunkprocess without threading, the application doesn't crash. However, as soon as I add in the threadpool, the application crashes and throws in the following errors. ChunkProcess run only emits (nothing else yet) signal shared_ptr which is a private member of ChunkProcess. After reading articles online, I found that shared_ptr is not thread safe unless you make a copy of it... so is there a way i can make a copy of it while using it as a signal?

```
ASSERT: "!d->ref.isShared()" in file tools\qlist.cpp, line 162
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

---

```
void MainWindow::parseCSV(QString file_name)
{
    QFile file(file_name);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return;
    QThreadPool *threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    QList<QList<QByteArray>>* data = new QList<QList<QByteArray>>;
    int count = 0;
    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        ++count;
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();
        data->append(line.split(','));
        if ( count > 10000 ) {
            ChunkProcessor* chunkprocess = new ChunkProcessor(data);

            connect(chunkprocess, 
                    SIGNAL(finished(std::shared_ptr<customClass::ProcessedData>)), 
                    this, 
                    SLOT(readingFinished(std::shared_ptr<customClass::ProcessedData>)));
//            threadPool->start(chunkprocess);
//            threadPool->waitForDone();
            chunkprocess->run();
            delete data;
            data = new QList<QList<QByteArray>>;
            count = 0;
         }
    }
    delete data;
}

void MainWindow::readingFinished(std::shared_ptr<customClass::ProcessedData> data)
{
    emittedData.append(data);
    qInfo()<<"got to finish reading";
}
```

Comment: Why do you allocate a QList on the heap? Create it on the stack!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely change it once I figure out the threading process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ASSERT: "!d->ref.isShared()" in file tools\qlist.cpp, line 162
```

this means that assertion has failed in `QListData` (private part of QList). This is not related with `shared_ptr`.
[Qt source](https://github.com/Satius/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.cpp) doesn't clarify what this assertion checks, but I'm guesing that you are doing something illegal on `QList` or you have some kind race condition on it.
It is hard to tell since you haven't show relevant part of code.

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

This means that your `QObject` (most probably `ChunkProcessor`) is destroyed from another thread and this object has active timer running.

Assuming that this is problem with `ChunkProcessor` you can fix it in couple ways:

1. do not use timer inside `ChunkProcessor`
2. do not transfer ownership of `ChunkProcessor` to the tread pool (`autoDelete()` should return `false`)

Note crash is not related with `shared_ptr`!

Also question is did you registered `std::shared_ptr<customClass::ProcessedData>` as a type?
If you didn't that it will not go through signal slot mechanism (since you have used automatic connection type)!

Comment: Thank you, setting the ChunkProcessor autoDelete to be "false" done the trick. I did registered the shared_ptr already, since the single run works, but not the threading run. Anyway, thank you for the autoDelete() suggestion.